# In the maven dependency tree does the parent dependency override the scope of the child?

Tags: java, maven

If i have the following output from running `mvn dependency:tree` are the jars that are brought in test or compile scope?

```
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger1:jar:2.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.5.0:compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example all three dependencies are effectively `test` scoped. As per [Dependency Scope docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) any transitive `compile` scoped dependency of a `test` scoped dependency becomes `test` scope:

> Each of the scopes (except for import) affects transitive dependencies in different ways, as is demonstrated in the table below. If a dependency is set to the scope in the left column, transitive dependencies of that dependency with the scope across the top row will result in a dependency in the main project with the scope listed at the intersection. If no scope is listed, it means the dependency will be omitted.

```
            compile     provided        runtime     test
compile     compile     -               runtime     -
provided    provided    -               provided    -
runtime     runtime     -               runtime     -
test        test        -               test        -
```

Answer (score 4):

It will be `test`. But this is not a general rule for *all* scope pairs. In your case, this holds:

> For the `test` scope, both `runtime` and `compile` scope transitive dependencies will be pulled in with the `test` scope, in the project.

More details can be found at https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes